# Swift - Format ios Charts PieEntry Label to include custom label that shows hours and minutes

Tags: ios-charts

I have a `pieChart` that is set up to track a user's time in 24 hours.

[PieChart Screenshot without event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3k5u.png)

I have programmed it to take a user's custom event and track its length of time spent in hours and minutes.

I have been trying to change the labels 15.50 and 8.50 and customize it to show 15 hours and 30 minutes, and 8 hours and 30 minutes.

I have studied the documentation but I haven't been able to find a way to customize each entry label?

[Example of piechart with 1 event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A53X1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a custom IValueFormatter

```
public class CustomPieValueFormatter: NSObject, IValueFormatter {
    public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?) -> String {
        
        let number = modf(value)
        let hour = String(format: "%.0f", number.0)
        let minute = String(format: "%.0f", 60 * number.1)
        return "\(hour) hour \(minute) minute"
    }
}
```

and set the value formatter to your PieChartData

```
let data = PieChartData(dataSet: dataSet)
        
data.setValueFormatter(CustomPieValueFormatter())
```